# Rails monkey patching didnt work well with TimeWithZone object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-3

I have this Time class extensions inside `lib/core_extensions/time/formatter.rb`

```rb
module CoreExtensions
  module Time
    module Formatter
      def to_formatted_utc
        puts({a: self.utc, b: utc})
        utc.strftime("%H:%M")
      end

      def to_formatted_tz
        in_time_zone.strftime("%H:%M")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why, does it doesn't do what I expected,

```rb
# Expected results is return 15:51

Time.zone.now                        # => Sat, 13 Mar 2021 22:51:29.217722286 +07 +07:00
Time.zone.now.utc                    # => 2021-03-13 15:51:29.217722286 UTC
Time.zone.now.utc.strftime("%H:%M")  # => 15:51

# Actual results when using to_formatted_utc

Time.zone.now.to_formatted_utc  # => 22:51
```

So I tried to debug it using `byebug`, and I see that `utc` didn't change the timezone to UTC format, so it's stays on  `+07:00` format, but when I tried to use `Time.zone.now.to_formatted_tz` it's add another 7 hours to the time. But it shouldn't do like that, as if I tried do this

```rb
Time.zone.now.in_time_zone  # it stays to +07:00, and the hours didn't changed
```

Why does this happen? and how to make it works like what I expected?

Thank you

> Ruby version: 3.0.0

> RoR version: 6.1.1

*Edit:*

Just found out that when I tried to byebug inside the method and execute `self`

it shows this

```rb
Time.zone.now                   # => Sat, 13 Mar 2021 22:51:29.217722286 +07 +07:00
Time.zone.now.to_formatted_utc  # => 2021-03-13 22:51:29.217722286 UTC
```

so the `+07:00` format changed to `UTC` but without subtracting the 7 hours, how to fix this?